# Get Uri of recorded video CameraX

Tags: android, uri, android-camerax

I am recording a video with the camerax library, I would like to retrieve the uri of the recorded file to open it with InputStream but it keeps giving me FILENOTFOUND

This is the code I use to start recording the video

```
contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, currentFile!!.name)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Movies/" + DataHolder.getInstance().albumName)
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis())
            }

            requireContext().contentResolver.run {
                val mediaStoreOutput = MediaStoreOutputOptions.Builder(
                    requireActivity().contentResolver,
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                    .setContentValues(contentValues)
                    .build()


                currentRecording = videoCapture.output.prepareRecording(requireActivity(), mediaStoreOutput)
                    .apply {  withAudioEnabled() }
                    .start(mainThreadExecutor, captureListener)

                val resolver = requireContext().contentResolver
                currentUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
```

And this is when I try to initialize InputStream:

```
 try {
            val resolver: ContentResolver = requireContext().getContentResolver()
            val fis: InputStream? = resolver.openInputStream(currentUri!!)

        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("asd", "Error File not found")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this path instead:

```
    val path = app.externalMediaDirs[0].absolutePath

    val dir = File(path, "/videos")
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        val success = dir.mkdirs()
        if (!success) {
            return
            // error/no file found
        }
    }
    val file = File(dir , name)
```

It has become tricky in the new sdk versions to write to storage

In this way you are placing the video in a directory you can later fetch it from

Comment: How can I do in the camerax ?

Comment: I can't find a method to get it to save a file using the "old system". I also need the recorded video to be in a specific camera album

Comment: @blacky99 ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
    }
}
You can either save the imageProxy or convert it and then save it

Comment: Thanks I will try. Also I see that videoCapture.output.prepareRecording support FileOutputDescription but when I open the video in the gallery app it's corrupted.